# H1 and H2 headings not recognized in SEO check. Angular

Tags: angular, seo, html-heading

Im having troubles with a website made in Angular 5. Even though i have H1 and H2 headings, in every SEO checker appears this error:
**Your page does not contain any H1 headings**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming. SEO questions may be asked on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Machavity: OP doesn’t ask for SEO advice.

Comment: @unor `in every SEO checker appears this error` Looks like an SEO problem to me. His code is clearly working, but not recognized by a third party. That's not a programming problem

Comment: @Machavity: The fact that it’s a SEO checker (instead of a validator, or an accessiblity checker etc.) shouldn’t be relevant. What matters is just: 1. OP has code, 2. this code produces warnings in a tool, 3. how to fix the code. -- If OP would ask if the warnings are a problem for SEO, or if it’s useful for SEO to test with these tools, then it would be an off-topic question asking for SEO advice. But OP doesn’t ask this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use angular universal. Without it, all html (h1, h2, content, ...) is added dynamically client side, which means that search engines and other bots cannot see them

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering